# An exercise about reflexivity of Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

Can anyone help me figure this out? I've come across this problem while answering some exercises about Hilbert spaces. I'm having a hard time.

[image: img]

I hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Think about Riesz Representation Theorem for Hilbert Spaces, this should help.

Comment: what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Let $(V,(.,.))$ be a real Hilbert space. We can use the Riesz isomorphism $R:V\to V^*$, $(Rx)y=(x,y)$. We will show that $$g=(R^*)^{-1}\circ R.$$ Both operators need some element $x\in V$ as argument and return element from $V^{**}$, i.e. linear continuous operators form $V^*$ to $\mathbb{R}$. These operator further need some $\varphi\in V^*$ as argument. Note that for given $\varphi$ there exists $y\in V$ such that $\varphi(x)=(y,x)$ for all $x\in V$. That means $R^{-1}\varphi=y$.

Left side: $g_x(\varphi)=\varphi(x)=(y,x)$.

Right side:  $((R^*)^{-1}\circ Rx)\varphi=((R^{-1})^*\circ Rx)\varphi=Rx(R^{-1}\varphi)=(Rx)y=(x,y)$.

Hence the left side is equal to the right.